# How to hide Windows Media Services server version header

Tags: appsec, http, windows-server

We have a Windows Media services server (used for streaming video) that returns the following banner in HTTP responses

Server: Cougar/9.6.7600.16564

I am trying to see if it is possible to stop the server from including this banner (or at least the exact version number) in order to reduce the information given out by it.

One possible answer could be using a HTTP proxy to strip the headers, though I was wondering if anyone knew of a solution similar to using URL Rewrite to hide ASP.NET server banners.

Comment: Have you tried [Change or modify a Response Header value using URL Rewrite](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2012/11/02/change-or-modify-a-response-header-value-using-url-rewrite/)?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Media Server is high-bandwidth, low CPU media server. So it can stream 20GBps with 10% CPU usage on 2008 produced server.

Because of that it's quite inefficient to put anything in front of it like proxy, and then, it's not really HTTP server, it has only HTTP headers.

There are no web browsers actually using it (except for playlists), it is used by specialized players on various devices, including Windows Media Player.

I haven't heard about method of disabling that string, and I think Nessus doesn't complain either if I remember correctly.